How to create an iOS or Android view as a component?
Can I create an iOS or Android view as a component? I want use Native VideoPlayer in Flame.
Like: NativeView -> Flutter Widget -> Flame Component
or NativeView -> Flame Component
I have successfully tried bridging a NativeView to a Flutter Widget, but I have no idea how to bridge it as a Flame Component.

No, you can't have an iOS or android view as a component inside of Flame. You can show it as an overlay though.

I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this but you can use a Flutter Widget as intermediary. Something like:

Create your NativeView.
Bridge your NativeView to your Flutter Widget (you mentioned you've already done this)
Create a Flame Widget Component with the WidgetComponent class that allows you to use a Flutter Widget as a component in your Flame.



import 'package:flame/components.dart';

class WidgetComponent extends WidgetComponent {
  WidgetComponent()
      : super(
          widget: FlutterWidget(), // Replace this with your Flutter Widget
          priority: 1,
        );
}



Also I add a link to the Flame component documentation if you need more information: https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/components.html

This would not work, you can't use widgets inside of Flame's component system.
